# How can subtract 2 floats which have been extracted from 2 other files with BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic, floating-point

I'm trying to get the difference between two numbers which I have taken from two files. I think my code will make sense:

I've tried to make it work by two different methods, didn't work. What I get as an output is zero (0).

```
#method 1
difference_btwn_eng_hrs_MX3_122=$(($(sed -n '1p' engine_hours_new_MX3_122.txt)-$(sed -n '1p' engine_hours_old_MX3_122.txt)))
echo "$difference_btwn_eng_hrs_MX3_122"

#method 2
new=$(sed -n '1p' engine_hours_new_MX3_122.txt)
old=$(sed -n '1p' engine_hours_old_MX3_122.txt)
echo "$new $old" | awk '{print $new - $old}'
```

Eventually I will use the difference to set intervals for email updates.

The values inside the files are 511.786 (new) and 509.768 (old),
and the error I get from the terminal is as follows:

```
line 40: 511.786-509.765: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".786-509.765")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with first example is that `bash` can operate only on integers and your second attempt with `awk` is simply not correct.

I propose to use `bc` for this job:

```
bc <<< "$new-$old"
```

`<<<` is so called [*here string*](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html), and it is basically the shorter form `echo "$new-$old" | bc`.

You can also modify your `awk` command if you like:

```
echo "$new $old" | awk '{print $1-$2}'
```

or (using *here string* as above):

```
awk '{print $1-$2}' <<< "$new $old"
```

Comment: Now the error has changed "bc: command not found". I've tried both of your suggestions. But no luck. Additionally with the calculation how would I assign it to a variable "difference", would it be difference="$new-$old" | bc, or difference=$new-$old | bc ? Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: @3kstc I understand that you don't have `bc`, but solution with `awk` doesn't work either? You can assign output to variable with *command substitution* `$()`: `difference=$(awk '{print $1-$2}' <<< "$new $old")`

Comment: it works! many thanks!  difference=$(awk '{print $1-$2}' <<< "$new $old") did the trick!

Comment: Now I have another problem;
How can I use `$difference` in an `if`statement?
`if [ "$difference" -ge "$limit"]; then
 echo "email sent out"
fi`

It doesn't like that I'm using a `float` in the condition, how could I bypass this?

Comment: [solved] used `int_difference=${difference%.*}`